# Jenkins - Storing curl output into file for future use

Tags: json, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I'm currently trying to make Jenkins job that runs if there's difference between the version number between 2 runs.

What I'm currently thinking on doing is by running curl on my webapp endpoint to get the webapp version. I'm looking to store this webapp version information onto jenkinsfile or any file.

The next time the jenkins job runs, it will do curl again to my webapp endpoint and compare the version between the current curl output and the saved version information from last run.

However, as I'm still kind of new to Jenkins, i have no idea on where to start to create the file to store the information i want, anyone have some recommendation or advice for me on how to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can write version number to any file(JSON,txt..etc) and read file into your workspace by using [pipeline-utility-steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/) by specifying the path in your jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0):

you can write a file to represent the state in a shared location and check it next run (no need any plugins):

```
# this will create initial file in jenkins home folder
curl http://version-check > ~/version
```

when u run the job u can use a simple sh script:

```
stage {
  sh """
    LAST_VER=$(cat ~/version)
    CURRENT_VER=$(curl http://version-check)
    if [ "$LAST_VER" = "$CURRENT_VER" ]; then
      echo "versions are equal"
    else
      echo "version are not equal"
      echo $CURRENT_VER > ~/version # update new state
    fi
  """
}
```